# How to extract parts of text with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to extract words (text) of given XML example:

```
<description>
[Партиден номер]: 2UW01AA [Номер на модела]: HP 14.1 Business Sleeve [Line]: Business [Screen size]: 14.1&quot; [Material]: Polyester [Color]: Black [Dimensions]: [more]
</description>
```

like this:

```
Партиден номер 2UW01AA
Номер на модела HP 14.1 Business Sleeve
Line Business
Screen size 14.1&quot;
Material Polyester
Color Black
```

Which exactly x-path can i use for this result?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`fn:replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-replace) function with a regex capture group:

```
replace(/description, "\[(.*?)\]:", "&#10;$1")
```

Comment: Ok, but i need to extract these fields through WP All Import in woocommerce attributes i need key for first word and value for second, that's my BIG problem...

Comment: @chrisbg:  Since you didn't ask anything about attribute-value pairs, you should post a new question rather than try to extend this one in comments.  And you should upvote/accept answers here based on what you actually asked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it with XPath 2.0 :

```
translate(substring-before(substring-after(//description,"["),": ["),"[]:",codepoints-to-string(10)  )
```

Output :

```
Партиден номер 2UW01AA 
Номер на модела HP 14.1 Business Sleeve 
Line Business 
Screen size 14.1" 
Material Polyester 
Color Black 
Dimensions
```

Comment: Super, i need to put these in woocommerce attributes as key:value pair. What's xPath for first and the second word?

Comment: @chrisbg: Again, please post a new question with this new request, and upvote/accept these answers based on the actually asked question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XPath will give you the description element, then you can use the [replace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function to remove the square brackets or replace them with line feeds.

Something like this, though the regexes will need to be more complicated if you need to handle square brackets in the values like `[more]`

```
replace(replace(normalize-space(description), '\[', '&#xa;'), '\]:','')
```